# How to know when an Angular page renders after initial creation

Tags: angular9

Angular 9

Use Case:

router directs user to `Page1`

`ngOnInit()` is called when `Page1` loads the 1st time...

from `Page1` the `router.navigate(['page2']);` sends the user to `Page2`...

from here after the user does some stuff, the `router.navigate(['page1']);` sends the user back to `Page1`...

now, what event is there to handle things that happen during the rendering of a page after the initial rendering has completed?

*I have things that I want to do each time this page comes into view... how would I handle this?

Comment: take a look on angular lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: I already looked there and didn't find the answer so that is what led me to make this post.